# Remove all packages that do not come with R

Tags: r, package

How can I remove all installed packages except `base` and `recommended`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would one want to do this instead of fresh R installation?

Comment: Updated to R 3.0.0 and have to rebuild all packages. Some give errors so I thought revert to vanilla and reinstall.

Comment: @geektrader that is the question I *should* have asked before attempting to answer! :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of

> Updated to R 3.0.0 and have to rebuild all packages.

just do

```
update.packages(..., checkBuilt=TRUE)
```

which is what I did on my R 3.0.0 (using `lib.loc=...` to point to my different local directories).  This will update everything you have *and which it can still get from repos* such as CRAN.  For `install_git()` etc, you are out of luck and need to reinstall.

But either way you do *not* need to remove the packages first.

Comment: I did `update.packages()` without the `checkBuilt=T` and run into errors. Was that the cause of my probs?

Comment: Well if a package no longer exists, or builds, or ... it will not work under this, but neither will it when you manually install it.  This just makes your life easier. YMMV.

Comment: @ECII Yes. `checkBuilt` checks if packages were built under the previous major release of R and marks them as old and in need of updating if TRUE, and will *try* to update them.

Answer (score 31):

Be CAREFUL! And read the docs before you try this:

```
# Pasted as a commented to prevent blindly copying and pasting
# remove.packages( installed.packages( priority = "NA" )[,1] )
```

By default this will remove packages from the first library in your `.libPaths()`. Otherwise you can specify the following argument to `remove.packages()`:

```
, lib = .libPaths()[1]
```

Comment: will this return my R installation to a vanilla state?

Comment: Assuming default install settings and default use of install. packages and nothing fancy in. REnviron file or .RProfile file then I think so! :-)

Comment: I just ran this code for R 3.0.0 and here are the only packages still available: base, boot, class, cluster, codetools, compiler, datasets, foreign, graphics, grDevices, grid KernSmooth, lattice, MASS, Matrix, methods, mgcv, nlme, nnet, parallel, rpart, spatial, splines, stats, stats4, survival, tcltk, tools, utils

Comment: I just ran the code and got `Error in find.package(pkgs, lib) : 
  there are no packages called ‘assertthat’, ‘backports’, ‘brew’, ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘clipr’, ‘clisymbols’, ‘commonmark’, ‘crayon’, ‘curl’, ‘desc’, ‘devtools’, ‘digest’, ‘evaluate’, ‘fansi’, ‘fs’, ‘gh’, ‘git2r’, ‘glue’, ‘highr’, ‘httr’, ‘ini’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘knitr...`, How could I solve this?

Answer (score 9):

Accepted answer no longer works (R 3.6.X), but this one does:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt = T, ask = F)
```

We use `checkBuilt=T` because this checks whether packages were built under an older version and need to be rebuilt (sometimes).

We use `ask=F` because otherwise we get a prompt for each package which is annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution available in the R-Blogger:

```
# create a list of all installed packages
 ip <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())
 head(ip)
# if you use MRO, make sure that no packages in this library will be removed
 ip <- subset(ip, !grepl("MRO", ip$LibPath))
# we don't want to remove base or recommended packages either\
 ip <- ip[!(ip[,"Priority"] %in% c("base", "recommended")),]
# determine the library where the packages are installed
 path.lib <- unique(ip$LibPath)
# create a vector with all the names of the packages you want to remove
 pkgs.to.remove <- ip[,1]
 head(pkgs.to.remove)
# remove the packages
 sapply(pkgs.to.remove, remove.packages, lib = path.lib)
```

Here is the link for the original post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-remove-all-user-installed-packages-in-r/

Answer (score 2):

If on Linux, the easiest thing is probably to remove the library folder, which by default is located in `/home/yourusername/R`.

On Fedora, for example, it is called `x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library`.
If the folder `/home/yourusername/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library` is deleted, it is automatically recreated at the following start of R. All default libraries are regularly available.

Comment: *it is automatically recreated at the following start of R* → **no** – it is only recreated once you ask for installing a package, and the system library is not writable for your user.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING, YOU WILL DELETE A LOT OF STUFF**

Sometimes uninstalling packages does not work, in which case you may want to delete the folder of the packages. This can be done from R assuming you have permissions.

```
sapply(paste(installed.packages( priority = "NA" )[, 2], installed.packages( priority = "NA" )[, 1], sep = "/"), unlink, recursive = T)
```

You can preview the paths to be delete by:

```
sapply(paste(installed.packages( priority = "NA" )[, 2], installed.packages( priority = "NA" )[, 1], sep = "/"), identity)
```

This call:

- Gets the list of installed non-base packages
- Makes a vector of their installed paths
- Loops over the paths
- Deletes each folder recursively