# How to remove all packages in R

Tags: r

Yesterday I tried to open a R Markdown in Rstudio. Rstudio forced me to download something, Now everytime I restart Rstudio or install package, it shows

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’
>
> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’"

I saw someone say that I can resolve this by removing all packages I have installed, but I only found the `remove.package` function, which can only remove one package at a time.

If I want to delete all packages, what should I do?
(I use Mac)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382647/remove-all-packages-that-do-not-come-with-r ?

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("yaml")` to solve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all packages that do not come with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382647/remove-all-packages-that-do-not-come-with-r)