# R gfortran / gcc-related / segfault error when installing forecast package

Tags: r, macos, gcc, gfortran

I recently updated my MacOS to version 12.5 and since then I have been unable to install certain packages in R.

For example, I am now trying to install the forecast package in R. When I try to install the package, I get the following error.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (12.3) than being linked (10.13)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (12.3) than being linked (10.13)
```

This appears to be a general problem when compiling certain packages, as I discovered after these same errors arose when I ran the "helloworld.cpp" test described [here](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/).

Based on the posts I've read (particularly this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999874/mac-os-x-r-error-ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option) and this [one](https://www.nistara.net/post/compile-issues-r/)), it appears that other people have experienced similar problems and one solution is to change the compile states in ~/.R/Makevars.

I searched for ~/.R/Makevars but I was not able to find an existing file; so I tried creating a new Document file called "Makevars" in the .r folder and adding the following text to the document:

```
VER=-11.3.0
CC=gcc$(VER)
CXX=g++$(VER)
CFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
CXXFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_2/lib/gcc/11
```

When I tried installing the forecast package again, I received a new error:

```
/bin/sh: gcc-11.3.0: command not found
make: *** [etscalc.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘forecast’
```

How can I fix this problem and install packages again? I would appreciate any help, since I've really been struggling with this.

As background, I have gcc installed (version 11.3.0) and Xcode command line tools installed.

---------------- Update ----------------

I tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270597/19620799), specifically:

1. I ran `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/gcc-11 /usr/local/bin/gcc` in the terminal
2. I then changed the Makevars file to

```
VER=-11
CC=gcc$(VER)
CXX=g++$(VER)
CXX11=g++$(VER)
CXX14=g++$(VER)
CXX17=g++$(VER)
CFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
CXXFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_2/lib/gcc/11
```

However, I still ran into a new error (one I can't even begin to understand) that prevented the package from loading properly.

```
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
sh: line 1: 16759 Segmentation fault: 11  R_TESTS= '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-save --no-restore --no-echo 2>&1 < '/var/folders/vw/t_hc3fcn2y5d975y2c4pvc2w0000gn/T//RtmpbcA9DF/file412625285e87'

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

Here is the session info

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.5

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1           tools_4.2.1              RcppArmadillo_0.11.2.0.0 Rcpp_1.0.9
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I try to run `brew upgrade` in terminal and restart after any OS updates with mac, sometimes doing that can fix issues with all the libraries R has to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was removing all R packages and then installing the forecast package.

I used the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382647/remove-all-packages-that-do-not-come-with-r)